# how to import menu and menu translation of different language in drupal 8 using drush

Tags: drupal, menu, translation, drupal-8, drush

I have added menus in main menu and did translation in two languages that is in French and German, now my problem is while importing menu and its configuration through [Drush](http://www.drush.org/en/master/) , those translation configuration is not imported as i noticed while exporting this configuration in my another site . So can anybody help me in , how can we able to import/export menu and its all translation that is done in different language using [Drush](http://www.drush.org/en/master/) . As I don't want to use `.csv` formatted files for this.

Comment: Have you tried before asking this question?

Comment: Yes i have used drush cex to export my configuration and i tried drush cim to import the configuration but in that .yml files no language translation configuration were there .

Answer (score 0):

Some how i manage to do this using [Translation Management Tool](https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt) module which is available for [drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org) , Other alternatives are migrate module and its dependency module's.